# How to properly estimate gas? Auto gas-estimation via safe transaction service not working

Tags: gnosis-safe

I'm creating gnosis transactions via my own interface using the safe-transaction-service createTransaction api. From my understanding, not providing a safeTxGas or any gas parameters makes gnosis automatically estimate the gas and the safe transaction sets the gas limit and such. However, this has resulted in countless failed transactions and inaccurate gas estimations.

What is the accurate way that the Gnosis Safe UI and other tools use to properly estimate transactions. Also, my transactions are Batched multisend transactions if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 0):

Failed transaction can have many reasons. More details on how `safeTxGas` behaves can be found in the [docs on the safe-contract repo](https://github.com/gnosis/safe-contracts/blob/a6504a9afdeac186a8cdb29ad68b189523c80eda/docs/safe_tx_gas.md#with-gas-refund).

If you share a transaction hash of a failed transaction it might be possible to provide more detailed feedback.

Comment: The failed transaction is "out of gas", and could be fixed by manually increasing gas prices/limits on the Gnosis transaction itself. When I generate transactions via the safe-transaction-api that the estimation is incorrect, leading to a poor UI where users have to manually increase the gas. Is this cause I set safeTxGas to 0? Not really sure

Comment: https://etherscan.io/tx/0x80ed1e66f39e955983ef4e4f74acfaa32dda768e0e02721665649f236972e393

Comment: How do you estimate the transaction with the Safe transaction api and what estimate did it return?  If you want to estimate the transaction completely yourself without a service, take a look at: https://github.com/gnosis/safe-core-sdk/blob/c0f6a4b573590ac7973fe24b4563bd7b3c29a232/packages/safe-core-sdk/src/utils/transactions/gas.ts#L19

Comment: The only thing I do is not provide the gas parameters and expect the safe transaction service to fill it in with createTransaction. Is this the correct way to do it?

Comment: No, the Safe transaction service does not perform any estimation. There is a `api/v1/safes/<safe_address>/multisig-transactions/estimations` endpoint, where estimations can be retrieved